# Relationship between complex and real Lp spaces.

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

The theory of integration of real functions is (as far as I know) usually extended to the complex case as follows:

Let $X$ be a set.
Given a function $f:X\to\mathbb C$,
define $\Re(f),\Im(f):X\to\mathbb R$ as $\Re(f)(x)=\Re(f(x))$ and $\Im(f)(x)=\Im(f(x))$ for every $x\in X$,
where $\Re$ and $\Im$ denote the real part and the imaginary part respectively.
Then,
it clearly is the case that $f=\Re(f)+i\Im(f)$.

Now,
if $(X,\mathscr A,\mu)$ is a measure space,
we say that $f:X\to\mathbb C$ is integrable if and only if $\Re(f)$ and $\Im(f)$ are integrable,
and we define
\begin{align*}
\int f~d\mu=\int\Re(f)~d\mu+i\int\Im(f)~d\mu.
\end{align*}
This implies in particular that
\begin{align*}
L^1(X,\mathscr A,\mu,\mathbb C)=L^1(X,\mathscr A,\mu,\mathbb R)+i\cdot L^1(X,\mathscr A,\mu,\mathbb R),\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $L^p(X,\mathscr A,\mu,\cdot)$ denotes the usual $L^p$ space.

**Question.** Equation (1) raises for me an interesting question: is it true that, for any $1\leq p<\infty$,
\begin{align*}
L^p(X,\mathscr A,\mu,\mathbb C)=L^p(X,\mathscr A,\mu,\mathbb R)+i\cdot L^p(X,\mathscr A,\mu,\mathbb R)
\end{align*}
holds? If not, for which $p$ does it hold and for which $p$ does it fail?

**Attempted solution:** By definition, $f\in L^p(X,\mathscr A,\mu,\mathbb C)$ means that $f^p$ is integrable. Now, working with $\Big(\Re(f)+i\Im(f)\Big)^p$ seems very cumbersome to me, so instead we could define functions $r:X\to[0,\infty)$ and $\theta:X\to[0,2\pi)$ such that $f(x)=r(x)\exp(i\theta(x))$.
In this case,
we have that
\begin{align*}
f=r\cos(\theta)+ir\sin(\theta).
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
f^p=r^p\cos(p\theta)+ir^p\sin(p\theta).
\end{align*}
However, I can't seem to get any further with this.

Comment: $f \in L^{p}(X, \mathscr A, \mu, \mathbb{C})$ means that $\int_{X} | f|^p d\mu < \infty$ or that $\int_{X} \left| \left(\mathfrak{R}(f)^2 + \mathfrak{I}(f)^2 \right)^{1/2} \right|^p d\mu < \infty$. See if that helps.